# Different result for each experiment even when n=1.000.000.000 in R, what's wrong?

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

Every time I run the code below, I get a different answer, mostly 1, 3, 4 or 5. However, since I set n to one milliard I think this is pretty strange, so I thought there must be something wrong with my code. This is my first time using R, but I'm not sure whether it's a mathematical error or a coding error.

**What I am to simulate:**

There are 40 people in a group, one of which is a doctor.

On day `0`, one person becomes infected; then `for i = 1, 2, ..., T`:

- day `i`: all the remaining healthy people has a probability of 0.15 of getting infected;
- day `i + 1`: the doctor heals 5 people at most (including himself);

The above stops till day `T`, when there is no more infected people.

**My code now (suspected wrong):**

```
SampleT <- function(n)
{
   for (k in 1:n)
   {
      T <- 0 # day 0
      X <- 39 # amount of healthy people
      Y <- 1 # amount of infected people
      cured <- 0 # amount of people cured by doctor
      while(cured < Y)
      {
         T <- T+1 # increase day by 1 in each loop
         infected <- sum((runif(X)<0.15)) # amount of people infected on day T
         X <- X-infected # remaining healthy people
         Y <- 40-X # total amount of people who have been infected at least once so far
         cured <- cured + 5
      }
      return(T)
   }
}

n <- 1000000000
T <- SampleT(n)
mean(T)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop only runs the first iteration.  Once 'return' is hit inside a function that's the end - it returns the result and exits the function.  If you were planning on getting a million results you need to store those somewhere and then return that result after the loop has run.  Here is an example to illustrate:

```
f <- function(n){
  for(i in 1:n){
    print(i)
    return(i)
  }
  # were you thinking it would return all 'n' values?
}
```

Then when we run it...

```
> f(30)
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Also try using `apply` functions:

```
N <- 10000
SampleT <- sapply(1:N, function(n) {
  T <- 0 # day 0
  X <- 39 # amount of healthy people
  Y <- 1 # amount of infected people
  cured <- 0 # amount of people cured by doctor

  while(cured < Y)
  {
    T <- T + 1 # increase day by 1 in each loop

    infected <- sum((runif(X) < 0.15)) # amount of people infected on day T
    print(infected)
    X <- X - infected # remaining healthy people
    Y <- Y + infected  # total amount of people who have been infected at least once so far
    cured <- cured + 5
  }
  return (T)
})


mean(SampleT)
```